# Git LFS - File size increases exponentially

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I would like to understand why a simple 109Mb video goes to over 1Gb when I push that one via **git lfs push --all origin main**

As you can see the file has 109Mb and it's inside the folder "Aulas":

[image]

```py
> git lfs track
Listing tracked patterns
    Aulas (.gitattributes)
Listing excluded patterns
```

But, when I try to upload, it increases horribly to 1Gb:

```py
> git lfs push --all origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': joe123
Password for 'https://joe123@github.com':
Username for 'https://github.com': joe123
Password for 'https://joe123@github.com':
LFS: Put https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/3895781639/9b/5e/9b5e4cb0a64dd66be85e152d6a0c7642d0ed96ded598d3d760?actor_id=28520843&key_id=0&repo_id=336106416: read tcp 127.0.0.1:55704->52.217.64.12:443: i/o timeout
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 1.0 GB | 1.9 MB/s, done.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `git lfs ls-files` print?

Comment: Are you pushing multiple versions of it?  Is the upload succeeding?  If not, Git LFS will retry, and the amount of data pushed will increase each time.  Run with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to see what's going on.

Comment: @ElpieKay it shows the video (the only file) that I would like to upload:
 ```9b5e4cb0a6 * Aulas/2021-02-04 21-22-32.7z```. And if I check for example the total size ```du -sh .git/``` in that folder, it shows: ```163M     .git/```

Comment: @bk2204 there are other files but they are pretty small sized compared to the video's one. The only file that's being tracked by  ```lfs``` is the ```*.7z``` format.

Comment: Try `git lfs ls-files --all`. There could be some lfs objects referred to by previous commits.